# Damage based arcanist build?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I am building an arcanist at level 5 with 20 point buy in pathfinder and i was looking for an arcanist build optimized for damage. It would also be helpful if there could be a level plan. I want to focus mainly on burst damage if possible. Like dealing fifty damage at the start of the fight.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed... [specific build](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-build-or-optimization-questions-on-topic) questions are on-topic. This could be fleshed out with questions in the comments, the obvious one being "what sources?" and perhaps "is there a theme (race/alignment/etc) that should be kept to?" but it's definitely a *specific build* as 5th level 'blaster' caster has few choices to optimize.

Comment: I voted re-open, but think we need some extra input otherwise it might get closed again as being too broad.

Comment: Optimized for what type of damage? Nova damage? Consistent damage? Damage against a specific type of creature? More details are needed to generate the build.